# Angular: How can I apply directive that've been introduced later then layout?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

Suddenly I've realized that I have no working plan (though I've tried a lot of things before asking this question here) for solving following problem. Say, we have following simple angular application ([jsfiddle #1](http://codepen.io/shabunc/pen/RPoyao)):

```
<div ng-app="debug">
  <ping/>
  <ping/>
  <ping/>
</div>
```

and

```
 var app = angular.module('debug', []);

    app.directive('ping', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<h1>PONG!!!</h1>'
      }
    })
```

This works as charm. OK, now let's try to declare directive later then layout was present, something like ([jsfiddle #2](http://codepen.io/shabunc/pen/mJOLEW)):

```
 var app = angular.module('debug', []);

// I've tried to use setTimeout initially but failed as well
var $timeout  = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$timeout');

$timeout(function() {

app.directive('ping', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h1>PONG!!!</h1>'
  }
})  

console.log('here');
}, 1000);
```

I see nothing. My question is - how can I recompile angular application and apply direcitives that've been declared in asychrnonous fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just select those elements and recompile them with its scope, instead of recompiling the entire app.

Example:

```
function compileThem(selector){
  var compile = angular.injector(['ng','debug']).get('$compile'),
     elmSet = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

 angular.forEach(elmSet, function(elm){
    var scope = angular.element(elm).scope();
    compile(elm)(scope);
  }); 

  elmSet = null;

}
```

and call it as:

```
compileThem('ping');
```

**[Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXYdYb)**

Comment: Thanks! That actually helped. The most frustrating part is that I've actually tried something very similar - I've tried to recompiled parent div container but hadn't succeeded.

Comment: @shabunc You are welcome!! Even if you recompile the parent that should work as well.

Comment: Hm, you are right!!! Will double check what differs between yours working code and mine.

Comment: @shabunc Sure.. timing of the call is important.. you can only select them after the elements are available in DOM.

Comment: I've forgot to add 'debug' to the injector )

Comment: oops that is a big one.. :)